# How do I find if my Wi-Fi card supports MIMO (Multiple Input Multiple Output)?

Tags: wifi, telecommunication

I want to know if my Wi-Fi card supports MIMO (Multiple Input Multiple Output), and specifically how to find the number of antennas.

Is there a command I can run to find out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If you're using windows** type in command line: `netsh wlan show all | find /I “MIMO”`.

If you see `MU-MIMO : Supported` then it means yes.

**I'm not sure how to do this in Linux** aside from checking network card model and looking at technical specification. That will give you 100% correct answer.

But You can try though this: `iw phy | grep index`; you will see something like this:

```
HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
```

If you see the index above 7 that means your card supports MIMO. Why is that ?

MIMO requires at least two antennas to work (means two spatial streams of data) and [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009#Data_rates) explains index / streams relation.

Comment: Thanks so much but i don't understand why they marked my question as a non-useful i have -2 mark :(